# HTML Form send to different address based on text response

Tags: php, html

I have a form on my site for coupon codes using paypal.  How can I make it so when they enter a certain coupon code, it brings them to a different part of the site?

i.e. you enter '10offbook', hit submit it brings u to books.php
if you enter '10offmagazine, hit submit it brings you to magazine.php

```
  <form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="couponCode"  placeholder="coupon code">
    <input type="submit" name="submitCouponCode" value="apply coupon">
</form>
```

Comment: Have you created a simple test page for a form in PHP?  One that has a form on it, upon submit calls itself `action = index.php`, checks for previous submits via `$_POST`, if previous test for particular values `if(.. ){ do something}`   Here, use this link. create your own file, test it, then you will be ready to quickly answer your own question.  ref: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/form-handler/

Answer (score 1):

On index.php, at the very top, you could check the value of the coupon code they entered, then redirect to different pages depending on the value of the coupon code.

```
if (isset($_POST['submitCouponCode'])) {
    $coupon = $_POST['couponCode'];
    if ($coupon == '10offbook') {
        header('Location: books.php');
        exit;
    } else if ($coupon == '10offmagazine') {
        header('Location: magazine.php');
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hopefully won't have to hardcode the values and instead use a database to check the inputted value against. But yea, +1